# running a code before showing context menu during customized right click in jquery

Tags: jquery, right-click, contextmenu

I used context menu plugin and was able to make if functional on the page I currently developing. At right click, I want to run a code (such as to highlight a selected row or column) before showing the context menu. Where can I insert the code. I used the plugin on this link.
http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/

My html:

```
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<table>
```

My js (context menu)

```
$("table tr td").contextMenu('myMenu',{
     onContextMenu: function(e){
         // I want to process the selected 'td' or 'tr' here... ex. highlight it
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the element that was right-clicked with `e.target`, e.g.:

```
$("table tr td").contextMenu('myMenu',{
    onContextMenu: function(e){
        $(e.target).effect("highlight", {}, 500);
    }
});
```

The [`highlight`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) effect is part of [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to highlight the parent row

```
 $("table tr td").contextMenu('myMenu',{
 onContextMenu: function(e){   
     var parent=$(e.currentTarget).parent();
     parent.addClass('SelectedRowColor');
 }
```

where SelectedRowColor row is the css class name .
hope that will help.